# Error in update query of sql server compact

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I tried this query

```
UPDATE       runnigorder
SET                orderid_new = (CAST( r.orderid as nvarchar(100) 
FROM runnigorder AS r))
WHERE        (runnigorder.dummyId = r.dummyId)
```

but its giving me an error that unable to parse query text.

[image]

please help me out from this.My Sql server compact version is 4.0.

this is my table [image]

Comment: Too many opening parenthesis before FROM

Comment: You have misplaced parenthesis, the last on third line shouldn't be there

Comment: after doing correction its giving me the same error

Comment: i tried your query @Pikoh but again it giving me an error- Optional FROM clause not allowed in this query type.
Column or expression 'orderid_new' cannot be updated.

Comment: I thought the  parenthesis where the only problem, but now analyzing your query does not make sense. What are you exactly trying to achive?

Comment: actually i have one table which contains column like orderid of type ntext and i have created another column name orderid_new of type nvarchar which contains null values and i want to insert in this column from orderid.

Comment: Then `UPDATE       runnigorder
SET          orderid_new = (CAST( r.orderid as nvarchar(100))) ` should do

Comment: yeah but its not working

Comment: Try without the cast, `UPDATE runnigorder SET orderid_new = r.orderid`

Answer (score -1):

Your query have some errors, try that

```
UPDATE r
SET r.orderid_new = CAST(r.orderid as nvarchar(100))
FROM runnigorder AS r
WHERE r.dummyId = r.dummyId
```

This will tranfer the data from the column **orderid** to **orderid_new** is that what ou want?

There was syntax and parenteses misplaced

Comment: having same error after trying your answer-Optional FROM clause not allowed in this query type.
Column or expression 'orderid_new' cannot be updated.

Comment: Maybe that: `UPDATE runnigorder SET orderid_new = CAST(orderid as nvarchar(100)) FROM runnigorder`